# Fibonacci rounding formula proof

Tags: sequences-and-series, fibonacci-numbers

Recently I had to solve a little problem related with Fibonacci numbers. I was using the Binet's formula for that:

> $$F_{n} = \frac{\Phi^n - \phi^n}{\sqrt{5}}$$

The effective solution I got by using [computation by rounding](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Fibonacci_number#/Relation_to_the_golden_ratio) formulas, related to Binet's formula that arises from simple inequality:

$$\left| \frac{\phi^n}{\sqrt{5}} \right| < \frac{1}{2}, \quad n \leq 0.$$

> $$F_{n} =\left\lfloor \frac{\Phi^n}{\sqrt{5}} + \frac{1}{2} \right\rfloor$$

I understand how it can be derived from above mentioned inequality, but I don't get it how I can derive that inequality rigorously in the first place. Any explanations would help me a lot! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, $-1<\phi<1$, so $-1<\phi^n\leq1$ for all $n\geq0$, and $\sqrt5>\sqrt4=2$.

Comment: Thank you! Now I get it!

Comment: $-2<1$, but $(-2)^2=4>1$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\phi=\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$, so
$$
|\phi|=\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}<1.
$$
Also, $\sqrt{5}>2$.

Comment: Thank you, it helped me!